# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client while trying to validate and insert with knex

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js, joi

I am trying to validate input form with Joi then perform an insert.
I thought I am to get the data first, then validate before inserting into db.

Before inserting I decided to console.log the result but got this error.

Also can someone please suggest a package for security. I heard about Helmet but I dont know how to apply to my code. Can someone please show me

> [Object: null prototype] {   bookname: 'dswdgefg',   summary:
>   'dstsdtgdrtfy\r\n              ',   isbn: '234325435',   select:
>   'Fruits' } [Object: null prototype] {   bookname: 'dswdgefg',
>   summary: 'dstsdtgdrtfy\r\n              ',   isbn: '234325435',
>   select: 'Fruits' } POST /addbooks 200 23.899 ms - 16 Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:482:11)
>       at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
>       at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>       at done (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1004:10)
>       at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:257:5)
>       at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:480:10)
>       at View.render (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
>       at tryRender (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
>       at Function.render (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
>       at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
>       at C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\app.js:41:7
>       at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
>       at trim_prefix (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
>       at C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\Users\dokunbam\Documents\Node\crudlist\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

This is my code

```
exports.addbooks = function (req, res)
{
    const bookname = req.body.bookname;
    const summaries = req.body.summaries;
    const isbn = req.body.isbn;
    const category = req.body.select;

    const schema = Joi.object().keys({
        bookname: Joi.string().trim().min(6).max(25).required(),
        summaries: Joi.string().trim().required(),
        isbn: Joi.number().required(),
        category: Joi.string().trim().required()

    });
    Joi.validate(req.body, schema, (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(result)
            res.send('an error occured');
        }
        console.log(result)
        //Perform knex insert into db
        res.send("successfully added");

    })

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On an error, you are first sending `an error occured`, and then sending again `successfully added`. You cannot do that, you can only send a response to the client once.

You need to stop the execution of your code after sending the error message.

```
Joi.validate(req.body, schema, (err, result) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(result)
        return res.send('an error occured');
    }
    console.log(result)
    //Perform knex insert into db
    res.send("successfully added");

})
```

Comment: Thanks, When I added "Return" as you have suggested. The console error is not showing again but I still got "an error occurred" on the page. so I changed the code like                         
     `Joi.validate(req.body, schema, (err, result) => {
  if(result){
   console.log(result)
   return res.send('successfully added');
  }else{
   console.log(result)
  //Perform knex insert into db
  res.send("an error occured"); 
  }`  that was when I got "successfully added"

Comment: I have discovered where the error is. There is a select field which I named select as well but the select name is not accepted. I change the name and it all went well. Thanks